CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent passes with different types
Had to write C# unit tests and one thing I do not understand is that why this method
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<string> {"turn:foo.com"}, new []{ new Uri("turn:foo.com"));

passes?
First parameter is a List of strings, second is an array of Uri types. List and Uri classes are the default .NET classes.
I searched for possible explanations and haven't found anything.

You seem to have a } missing.

Also I cannot reproduce this behaviour after adding the }.

What CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() are you using?  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()?  NUnit.Framework.CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent()?  Something else? And which version of .NET and the CollectionAssert() library are you using?  Please [edit] your question to clarify, ideally with a [mcve].

TL/DR: this could happen if Object.Equals(object? other) has been overridden in one of the different types to return true for objects of the other type.  In the case of Uri, Uri.Equals(object? other) will return true for string inputs that are equal to the Uri's value.
Full explanation: This doesn't seem to be documented, but a check of the reference source shows that Uri.Equals(object? comparand) has been overridden to return true when comparand is a string that is equal to the Uri's value:

// we allow comparisons of Uri and String objects only. If a string
// is passed, convert to Uri. This is inefficient, but allows us to
// canonicalize the comparand, making comparison possible


I.e. if I have string and Uri values, the return of object.Equals(a, b) is asymmetric and depends on which I pass in first:
var @string = "turn:foo.com";
var uri = new Uri("turn:foo.com");

Console.WriteLine("object.Equals(@string, uri) = {0}", 
                  object.Equals(@string, uri)); // False
Console.WriteLine("object.Equals(uri, @string) = {0}", 
                  object.Equals(uri, @string)); // True

Demos fiddles: .NET 4.7.2, .NET 8.
Your question does not specify the library from which CollectionAssert is taken, but if its CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() happens to treat its arguments as non-generic IEnumerable or ICollection types[1] and so only enumerates through the items as object values, and happens to call object.Equals(a, b) with the Uri value in the first argument, you will get the behavior you are seeing.
For example, using NUnit.Framework.Legacy.CollectionAssert, while the assert shown in your question actually fails (perhaps there is a typo in your question):
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new List<string> {"turn:foo.com"}, 
                               new []{ new Uri("turn:foo.com")}); // FAILS

Transposing the arguments makes the assert succeed:
CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(new []{ new Uri("turn:foo.com")}, 
                               new List<string> {"turn:foo.com"}); // PASSES

Demo here.

[1] This is true e.g. for  Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() which takes non-generic ICollection values as arguments, and NUnit.Framework.Legacy.CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent() which takes non-generic IEnumerable values a arguments.
